# Angular 14 Universal, ReferenceError: EventTarget is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to add SSR to my application in angular 14, but when I start serve:ssr it gives me the error.

```
class MockMediaQueryList extends EventTarget {
                                 ^

ReferenceError: EventTarget is not defined
```

I imagine it's a problem with @angular/flex-layout, but looking inside node_modules I can't find the error code (nor looking inside the base code)

```
@angular 14.2.X
@nrwl 15.0.X
@angular/flex-layout 14.0.0-beta.41
npm 6.14.17
node v14.20.0
```

Comment: This package was deprecated. My suggestion was please don't user this package @angular/flex-layout

Comment: In the end I solved using node version 16 instead of version 14

Comment: @AmanGojariya Yes, unfortunately I already know that this package is discontinued, but every single component I have depends on this blessed library